# Vaadin - Cant build docker image

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

im trying to build an docker image of my project.
When im running the command following error occur:

```
#19 128.8 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.2.1:build-frontend (default) on project PROJECTNAME: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.2.1:build-frontend failed: Unable to validate the license, please check your internet connection. If you need to work offline then please go to https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?getOfflineKey=MACHINEKEY to retrieve an offline key. For troubleshooting steps, see https://vaadin.com/licensing-faq-and-troubleshooting. -> [Help 1]
```

Im using Vaadin Pro (Student).

I tried to generate an offline key, but when I paste in the machine key or opening the link of the error message, nothing happens.

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

To use paid Vaadin Pro components you'll need an [offline server key (Vaadin License key)](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/licenses).
You can then pass the key to the `docker build` via the means of Docker build-args:

1. Add the following to your `Dockerfile`: `ARG offlinekey`; `ENV VAADIN_OFFLINE_KEY=$offlinekey`
2. Build the app with `$ docker build --no-cache -t test/yourapp:latest --build-arg offlinekey='eyJra.....the_very_long_1600_character_offline_key_text_blob' .`

Please see https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin-boot for an example on the `Dockerfile` and the process of building and running your app in Docker.

Comment: The Vaadin support told me, that the Student Pro license isn't like to normal Pro license. The Student license gehts renewed every two weeks. So I can't generate an offline license.